# removing left-over space from contents in scaleimagelabel

Tags: codenameone

On the first picture there is left-over space in top and bottom and on second picture there is left-over space in left and right. This of course depending on the device screen size. But is it possible to remove or reduce this overhead space from scaleimagelabel?

I tried to set margin and padding to zero, but this does not remove the overheading space. And as I see it, it should be in the content area.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the `ScaleImageLabel` uses the "fit" option which means it will preserve aspect ratio when scaling and use white space around the image depending on background transparency setting. You can choose one of these 3 options for scaling:

[image: Scaling]

E.g. If you want the images to fill but crop a bit you can do this:

```
lbl.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL);
```

Comment: well, I would like to have the aspect ratio in place. The area I'm talking about is the area above and under the image which take up a lot of the place on small screens (the white on my image is actually part of the image, but the grey area above and under takes up approx 25% of the screen. If the label contents could somehow cut off this space it would be easier to make app's for small screens)

Comment: I think that this isn't a question of margin or scaling but rather a question of layout. What layout managers are you using here? Is there a scrollable parent container?

Comment: It is TableLayout with a BoxLayout as parent and no scroll

Comment: Is box layout of the form? If so the content area should be scrollable by default on the Y axis. If you enable scrolling the table layout will take up its preferred size and should look more like the image on the right hand side

Comment: If I enable scroll I get another problem. I'm using touch on large image and zoom area to little picture, but with scroll enabled the screen is moving when I try to position arrow on large image. However, I found a workaround: Using scaled and then calculate percentage for Height so I get a square image. Seems to minimize the waste area and I can live with it. So thx for your help